# for loop with GET request in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am in the process of creating a Python script that will allow me to process multiple GET requests by using a "for" loop. However, I am not getting the results that I expect. Here is what my code looks like:

```
import requests
import json

authorization_code = "api:122222:1111112:LA5"
members = [12345,1234567]
for member in members:
   url = "http://api.example.com/v1.14/member?id="+str(member)  


header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

member_check = json.loads(response.text)
final_member_status = member_check["response"]["member"]["is_expired"]

print str(member) + " expired status: " + str(final_member_status)
```

In this example, I see member "1234567" printing out as part of my structure at the end. What I am expecting is the loop to go through each one of these members and make a GET request for each one and then return a specific key value for each member (in this case, the key is called "is_expired". Therefore, I should see:

```
member 12345 expired status: false
member 1234567 expired status: false
```

If anyone could help I would appreciate it. My guess is that I am not using my loop correctly or that I have in the wrong place.

Thanks.

Comment: is the code here indented as your code or a typing error?

Comment: My code was NOT indented and this fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indentation, you are welcome:

```
import requests
import json

authorization_code = "api:122222:1111112:LA5"
members = [12345,1234567]
for member in members:
    url = "http://api.example.com/v1.14/member?id="+str(member)  


    header = {"Authorization": authorization_code}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

    member_check = json.loads(response.text)
    final_member_status = member_check["response"]["member"]["is_expired"]

    print str(member) + " expired status: " + str(final_member_status)
```